# A Question with both poisson and gamma distribution

Tags: probability

> Suppose X denote the number of bacteria per cubic centimeter in a particular liquid and that X has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, further, suppose that $\lambda$ varies from location to location and has a Gamma distribution(2,5) If we randomly select a location
>
> a)What is the expected number of bateria $cm^3$?
>
> b) what is the standard deviation of the number of bacteria $cm^3$

I am confused by the combination of two distribution. If $\lambda$ is of Gamma(2,5) then is it equal to $25e^{-10}X$ ?
so $E(x)$ is the same?  any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Is $\Gamma(2,5)$ [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) in terms of shape and scale or shape and rate? In either case we can find $\lambda$ from both, and then use this $\lambda$ as the mean of the Poisson distribution.

Comment: the question only says Gamma(2,5) distribution, so I don't really know..

Comment: You are seeking a parameter-mix distribution, in particular a Poisson-Gamma mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, what you have is a called a mixture, and you should be able to compute the pmf of this mixture by using the total law of probability.  The idea is that you need to express your Poisson as being conditioned on $\lambda \sim \Gamma(2,5)$. So, let's see:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X=x) &= \int_0^\infty \dfrac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!} f_\Gamma(\lambda) \, \mathrm{d}\lambda \\
&= \int_0^\infty \dfrac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!} \dfrac{\lambda e^{-\lambda/5}}{5^2 \Gamma(2)} \, \mathrm{d}\lambda \\
&= 5^x 6^{-x-2} (x+1). 
\end{aligned} $$

Now we can use this to get, e.g., the expected value
$$E[X] = \sum_{x \ge 0} \dfrac{x(x+1) 5^x}{ 6^{x+2}} = 10.$$

The variance would follow in a similar manner.

Comment: so it's the negative binomial distribution?

Comment: According to Wolframalpha $P(X=x)$ is wrong
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral+%28e%5E%7B-y%7D+y%5Ex%29%2F%28x%21%29++e%5E%28-y%2F5%29%2F%285%5E2+*+Gamma%282%29%29+dy+from+0+to+infinity

In fact
$$P(X=x)=\frac{1}{30}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^x$$

Comment: @baudolino By Fubini the answer should be the same as mine. Finally I figured out whats wrong apart from the integral value. The Gamma density function is also wrong. You have to stick to one parameter shape...

Comment: @DimaMcGreen In Mathematica, the following statement (pretty self-explanatory) `Integrate[PDF[PoissonDistribution[q],x]*PDF[GammaDistribution[2,5], q], {q,0,Infinity}]` evaluates to my answer from above (substitute $q$ with $\lambda$).

Comment: @baudolino Might be, I don't have Mathematica. But looking on the formula, I can tell its not right. But you do agree, that we should have the same result, since the approach is the same, its the integral order thats different?!

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda\sim \Gamma(p,b)$, I think you are looking for
$$E(X) = E\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda}\right) = E(\lambda) = \frac{p}{b}
$$
and
$$ Var(X) = Var(\lambda) = \frac{p}{b^2}
$$

Comment: so the when doing mixture you do the discrete case first? 
and the answer here would be $2 \over 5$?

Comment: well it's not a rule to do the discrete case first. But since you have a random variable distributed according to a Poisson distr. with a random parameter $\lambda$, there is no way to do it differently.