# Poisson distribution proof

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Looking over an exam and I have no idea how to finish when proving this:

Prove that for a Poisson r.v. X, if the parameter $\lambda$ is not fixed and is itself an exponential r.v. with parameter 1, then:

$P(X = x) = (\frac{1}{2})^{x+1}$

My attempt:

$P(x) = \frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!}$

$\lambda = \frac{1}{\beta}exp(\frac{-x}{\beta})$, $\beta = 1$

$\lambda = e^{-x}$

$P(x) = \frac{e^{-x^2}e^{e^{-x}}}{x!}$

And now I'm stuck...

Thanks so much in advance, this website is gonna make me pass stats :)

Comment: I've answered a similar question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466929/a-question-with-both-poisson-and-gamma-distribution/466956#466956

Just replace the Gamma(2,5) with your Exponential and work the calculation.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've the hang of it!

Answer (score 1):

The solution basically boils down to:

$$
P(X=x) = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!} e^{-\lambda} \, \mathrm{d}\lambda
$$
which after a little manipulation evaluates to
$$
P(X=x) = \dfrac{2^{-(x+1)}\Gamma(x+1)}{x!}=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{x+1} $$
since for discrete r.v. (i.e. Poisson), $\Gamma(x+1) = x!$